# How to Skip values of $EmptyMap of size=0 in scala

Tags: scala, maps

I am using a SQL query to get data and map the column name and and value to a tuple, then map the set of tuples to a map list, I need to skip the maps with size 0 and only get the maps with values.

My code and results as follows.

`SELECT orbkn_surgery_procedures_order_status,orbkn_surgery_procedures_id,orbkn_surgery_procedures_or_booking,orbkn_surgery_procedures_created_date_time,orbkn_surgery_procedures_order_id FROM OR_Cube_for_surgery`

```
    try {
  NamedDB(Symbol(db)) readOnly { implicit session =>

      Right(

        SQL(sql + " LIMIT 50000")
          .map(_.toMap())
          .list
          .apply()
      )
  }
```

Result set I get

```
Right(List(Map(), Map(orbkn_surgery_procedures_id -> 41, orbkn_surgery_procedures_or_booking -> 734, orbkn_surgery_procedures_order_id -> 105610),Map(orbkn_surgery_procedures_order_status -> OPD, orbkn_surgery_procedures_id -> 174, orbkn_surgery_procedures_or_booking -> 883, orbkn_surgery_procedures_order_id -> 100788), Map(orbkn_surgery_procedures_order_status -> IPD, orbkn_surgery_procedures_id -> 175, orbkn_surgery_procedures_or_booking -> 884, orbkn_surgery_procedures_order_id -> 106321), Map(orbkn_surgery_procedures_order_status -> IPD, orbkn_surgery_procedures_id -> 176, orbkn_surgery_procedures_or_booking -> 886, orbkn_surgery_procedures_order_id -> 106354),Map(), Map(), Map(), Map(), Map(), Map(), Map(), Map(), Map(), Map(), Map(), Map()))
```

I need to get rid of those `Map()` and get only the set of Maps(WITH ANY DATA)

Comment: Remove the empty value using the "filterNot(_.isEmpty)"

Comment: @Dhirendra Can you exactly say the place where should I use this? I tried the above and it didnt work for me.

Comment: Right after the call to `apply`. You can either `.filterNot(_.isEmpty)` or `.filter(_.nonEmpty)`.

Comment: @stefanobaghino so it would be like apply().filterNot(_.isEmpty).? But wouldn’t this return boolean??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to filter the list of `Map`s to remove the empty ones, something like this:

```
Right(
  SQL(sql + " LIMIT 50000")
    .map(_.toMap())
    .list
    .apply()
    .filter(_.nonEmpty)
)
```

However it would be better to put the filter in the SQL if possible and let the database do the work.